# get value from object arraylist and show it in another activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist

```
public class User implements Parcelable
{
 private  int Id;
 private  String Name;
 private  String Desg;

 public User() {
     super();
}
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return 0;
 }

 public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(Name);
    dest.writeInt(Id);
    dest.writeString(Desg);

}
  private User(Parcel in){
        this.Name = in.readString();
        this.Id = in.readInt();
        this.Desg = in.readString();

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<User> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<User>() {

        @Override
        public User createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new User(source);
        }

        @Override
        public User[] newArray(int size) {
            return new User[size];
        }
    };
public int getId() {
    return Id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.Id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.Name = name;
}
 public String getDesg() {
    return Desg;
}
public void setDesg(String desg) {
    this.Desg = desg;
}
}


public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<User> userlist = new ArrayList<User>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);

       Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);


        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

         public void onClick(View v)
         {
             EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
             EditText desg= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.desg);
             EditText id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id);
             User user = new User();
             user.setName(name.getText().toString());
             user.setDesg(desg.getText().toString());
             user.setId(Integer.parseInt(id.getText().toString())); //in case if type is integer



         if(userlist.contains(user))
             {
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Already Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             else{
                 userlist.add(user);


             }
                 Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                 intent.putExtra("userlist",userlist);
                 startActivity(intent);
                 finish();
         }
     });

}



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   ListView show;
   ArrayList<User> myList= new ArrayList<User>();      
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
     show = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
     myList=   getIntent().getParcelableExtra("userlist");
     ArrayAdapter<User> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<User>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, myList);
     show.setAdapter(adapter);

     System.out.println(show);

     show.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         CheckedTextView checkedTextView = ((CheckedTextView)view);
         checkedTextView.setChecked(!checkedTextView.isChecked());
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }      
     });         
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

I am storing the user input of different datatype in an arraylist and on button click I want to show that user input (arraylist) in a list view of checkboxes. But this code is not working even it has no error. anyone please tell me may be there is some logical issue here?

Comment: use putParcelableArrayListExtra() with intent to pass array list between activities. may be this will solve problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Best Way**

Put

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("userlist" , userlist);
```

Retrieve

```
myList= (ArrayList<User>) getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("userlist");
```

**Alternate Way**

You have to put individually each item of arraylist in intent extra and then retrieve it accordingly.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
for (int i = 0; i<userlist.size(); i++)
     intent.putExtra("userlist_"+i , userlist.get(i));
intent.putExtra("userlist_size" , userlist.size());
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Now to retrieve it.

```
ArrayList<User> myList= new ArrayList<User>();  
int size = getIntent().getIntExtra("userlist_size" , 0);
for(int i=0; i<size ; i++){
   myList.add((User)(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("userlist_"+i)))
}
```

Comment: application is running with the alternative way but it is showing com.example.userlist User@47q67608 in the listview

Comment: That is the name of object. Try using something like `myList.get(0).getDesg()` It'll give you exact value store in object. @hira

Comment: not working i have checked the log things are passing correctly but there is issue while getting them.....com.example.userlist.User is getting in Log too @Shaishav Jogani

Comment: @hira I check you code, which you posted in question. It seems fine and should work properly. What's the error you are getting in MainActivity

Comment: no error its running but in listview i am not getting the value that i m giving as input...it is getting com.example.userlist.User@426e54 all time

Comment: @hira can you post. what are you wrote in `Log`. I mean how you displaying value of `User`

Comment: Log.v("hello", User.class.getName());

Comment: @hira this what you are doing totally wrong. `User.class.getName()` will give you name of the `User` class. To get particular value of object of `User` class use something like this in your app.`myList.get(0).getName()`

Comment: See how arraylist work. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use intent extras in passing values from one activity to another. Here's an example of sending values to the target activity:

`Intent intent = new Intent(OriginActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("variableName", variableValue);
startActivity(intent)`

This sends the data "variableName" with its corresponding value to the target activity. In order to retrieve the sent data, you must first get the instance of the intent in the target activity and then call a type-specific function to return the value. You must also supply a default value in case the function cannot find the specified data or the data does not exist. If for example you want to retrieve an **integer**, you can do it this way:

`int retrievedValue= getIntent().getIntExtra("variableName", defaultValue);`

PS: You might want to make it a habit separating your activities, models, etc. in different class files.